# Is the equator a line?

Tags: geometry, circles

The equator is a circle that goes around the earth. Does that mean that it is a line?

[image]

I'm guessing that it is because it is infinite. At the same time, it's overlapping. The real question is, is a circle technically an infinite line?

Comment: This is not a bad question, but it has been downvotes because you have not included your own thoughts

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Ok, I'll add some

Comment: Wonderful: +1 ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) we can extract:

> Thus in differential geometry a line *may* be interpreted as a geodesic
>   (shortest path between points), while in some projective geometries a
>   line is a 2-dimensional vector space (all linear combinations of two
>   independent vectors). This flexibility also extends *beyond mathematics*
>   and, for example, permits physicists to think of the path of a light
>   ray as being a line.

Hence the Equator can be interpreted as a line in the geodesic sense.

Answer (score 1):

I assert that the equator is *not* a line.

From [*Wolfram MathWorld*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line.html):

> A line is a straight one-dimensional figure having no thickness and extending infinitely in both directions.

If you look at Earth in terms of orthogonal unit vectors (i.e., $\mathbf i$, $\mathbf j$, $\mathbf k$ or equivalents) then the equator occupies at least two dimensions.

If you look at Earth in terms of [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html), where the origin is Earth’s center, then equator is of the form $r=k$ for a constant $k$. Thus only one dimension is used to define it. However, its finiteness/infiniteness is debatable:

- If your coordinate system is defined such that $\theta$ is restricted to vary on $[0,2\pi)$ then the equator has a finite length of $2\pi k$.
- If your coordinate system is defined such that $\theta$ can vary across $(-\infty,\infty)$ then the locus (or set of points defined by a criterion in some way) $r=k$ is infinite.

However, notice that $r=k$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ and $r=k$ for $\theta\in(-\infty,\infty)$ — though they appear differently in numerical form — overlap entirely on a graph. This is part of the reason why $\theta$ is almost always restricted to $[0,2\pi)$ (which is mentioned in the linked article).

Thus, in the conventional sense, the equator is not a line.

You also ask if a circle is an infinite line. In response to that, I ask you, what is the length of that line, or in other words, its circumference? There are many reasons to not think of a circle as an infinite line. I’ll leave that investigation to you; perhaps you’d like to write a paper on it one day....